# How launch google assistant at a specific time?

Tags: android, alarm

I'm wondering if it's possible to launch google assistant in a given time so to start news briefing for example? 
I was looking for this, and I didn't see any possible idea ..

Comment: do you know how to start google assistant on a button click for exapmle?

Comment: using intent, isn't? actually I mean how to force google assistant to read news briefing with a voice because as I know isn't possible with writing the command!

Answer (score -1):

**Use Intent to launch the google assistant application.**

Put the below code in ur alarm code.

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.googleassistant");
if (launchIntent != null) { 
    startActivity(launchIntent);
}
```

Comment: great, but is useful to make google assistant read news briefing with a voice in this way ?